# What is the most basic and straight way to create our own sum function using recursion in Rust

Tags: rust

How about this?

```rs
fn my_sum(ns: &Vec<usize>) -> usize {
    match ns.split_first() {
        None => 0,
        Some((n, ns)) => n + my_sum(&ns.to_vec()),
    }
}
```

I wanted to use `first` and `rest` in Clojure fashion.
However, I coundn't find any function like `rest` in [the document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Rust doesn't make any guarantees about tail call optimisation, so recursion is likely to be a lot less efficient than a loop or iterator combinators, and could overflow the stack for large inputs.

Comment: @PeterHall anyway the OP code is not tail recursive :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `rest` function in the standard library. Instead, you can keep the code you have currently with `split_first`, or you can use a [slice pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html):

```rust
fn my_sum(ns: &Vec<usize>) -> usize {
    match ns.as_slice() {
        [] => 0,
        [first, rest @ ..] => {
            first + my_sum(&rest.to_vec())
        }
    }
}
```

However, note that `to_vec` performs a heap allocation, so calling `my_sum` recursively is very inefficient. Instead, you can work with slices directly:

```rust
fn my_sum(ns: &[usize]) -> usize {
    match ns {
        [] => 0,
        [first, rest @ ..] => {
            first + my_sum(&rest)
        }
    }
}

let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

my_sum(&vec);
// or
my_sum(vec.as_slice());
```

And finally, one should always make tail recursion when possible:

```rust
fn my_sum(ns: &[usize], acc: usize) -> usize {
    match ns {
        [] => acc,
        [first, rest @ ..] => my_sum(rest, acc + first),
    }
}
```